# Who earns the interest during a naked short sell, where the shares haven't been located yet and fails to deliver

Tags: interest, shorting-securities

When someone naked short sells, who do they pay the interest to?

If they never locate the shares, then there isn't a shareholder to pay. Do they pretend to pay interest? Do they actually pay interest? Who collects it?

Comment: You can't sell naked without borrowing first

Comment: I don't know how this is on topic...

Comment: @Aganju you don't know if I have that capability or not. some market participants do short before locating a share and this is called a naked short.

Comment: @Aganju the word "naked" means precisely that you didn't borrow first (and it's illegal)

Comment: @user253751 illegal under some circumstances, the consequences not always a real deterrent. who pays who during a naked short?

Comment: It's an interesting question.  I would guess that if there's no actual lender (naked shorting), there's no payment of borrow cost to anyone.  You can't even pretend to pay someone who doesn't exist.  And even if you did (who would you send it to?), doing so  wouldn't disguise or protect you from discovery.  It's the exchanges and/or the SEC who are looking for violations.  Somewhat non sequitur:  If the naked short is discovered, do they bust the trade? What happens to the innocent buyer who gets no delivery?  No gain? No loss?  Thank you very much, goodbye?

Comment: @BobBaerker I gather its just fractional reserve of shares, so what are essentially Contracts for Difference just continue trading in perpetuity until the company is dissolved. Dissolution doesn't often leave anything left for shareholders to make any claim on assets so it likely almost always works out. I wasn't curious about any statement on discovery of the naked short, short interest is still reported and sometimes easy to detect when the % of float shorted is more than 100%.

Comment: @BobBaerker Given the whole clearinghouse collateral debacle, I would imagine one of the brokers or the clearinghouse has to buy them at market price and then sue the one who failed to deliver

Comment: @user253751 - That's a logical possibility.